# Executing Function by String Name

Tags: python, string, pandas, function, rolling-computation

I have a pandas series defined as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
series = pd.Series([11,9,13], index=[1,2,3])
```

I compute the rolling series using the following:

```
rolling = series.rolling(window=3, min_periods=3, center=True)
```

I now want to apply a given `method` to this rolling `series` as follows:

```
method = 'median'
if method == 'median':
    series = rolling.median()
elif method == 'mean':
    series = rolling.mean()
```

**Can this be achieved just using the string name instead?** For example I would do something like:

```
if method in ['mean', 'median']:
    series = rolling.method()
```

Thanks for any help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, you can use the built-in `getattr` function.

```
if method in ('mean', 'median'):
    series = getattr(rolling, method)()
```

In case it seems shady:

```
>>> getattr(rolling, median) == rolling.median
True
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. So there's no public API?

Comment: @AlexJ.R.Lewis `__getattribute__` *is* public API, no? :) Anyways, I've updated my question to use `getattr` instead, in case the dunders looked hacky.

Comment: True - but I guess the rule-of-thumb is don't touch `_var` and definitely don't touch `__var` ...